# Jquery custom rule dynamically added

Tags: jquery

I have a custom rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("greaterThanStartPrice", function(value, element, param) {
return this.optional(element) || (parseFloat(value) > $(param).val());
}, "\"Reserve Price\" must be greater than \"Start Price\"");
```

to check that a value entered into input box b is greater than input box a. This rule works great however the form field it is applied to is dynamic so I also have:

```
$("#txtReservePrice").rules("remove");
```

to remove the rule. The rule is initiated:

```
$("#frmEditListingAuction").validate({
    meta: "validate",
    rules : {
        txtReservePrice:{ 
            greaterThanStartPrice:"#txtStartPrice",
        }
    }
});
```

I am having trouble re-adding the rule back on. I have tried:

```
$("#txtReservePrice").rules("add", "greaterThanStartPrice");
$("#txtStartPrice").rules("add", "greaterThanStartPrice");
```

but apart from that I am a little lost. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out if anyone wants to know

```
$("#txtReservePrice").rules("add", {greaterThanStartPrice:"#txtStartPrice"});
```